# how to make navigation drawer + scrollable tabs in a single app?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-launcher, android-scrollable-tabs

I first made scrollable tabs in my app and it is working perfectly then I also want to insert navigation drawer in this app .I coded all the thing but navigation drawer is not visible .

i think this is because I made scrollable tabs main activity as launcher and navigation one is default .

So plz guide me as how can I set two classes as Launcher or is there some other method?

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager with sliding tab functionality and sliding navigation menu are one of the most popular Android open source components.

There're literally hundreds of clones of such - let me give you the links below.

Check out their demos, compile them, and play around with them. And, let's contribute some time to their projects!

[image]

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

[image]
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: thanks for your response , but I want both of these features in a single app .

Comment: If you want these two in a single app, you just have to import them both in your app library, configure in `xml` at appropriate places, then programmatically load them in your `.java`.